# Reward ad callback is not firing

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

i have a game and when the player loses their lives, i want them to be able to watch a video for a second chance.

I am using unity version 2018.1.1f1 person and i have downloaded the admob unity plugin version 3.13.1

So if the player agrees to watch an ad, the ad will play and then resume the game without firing the callback that rewards the player. This is my code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RewardAd : MonoBehaviour {
    private BannerView bannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;
    private float deltaTime = 0.0f;
    private static string outputMessage = string.Empty;

    public AudioSource musicPlayer;
    public Player player;

    public Text UIText;

    public static string OutputMessage
    {
        set { outputMessage = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {

        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511";
        #else
        string appId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

        //Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
        this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        // RewardBasedVideoAd is a singleton, so handlers should only be registered once.
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdOpening += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdStarted += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdClosed += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;
        this.rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // Calculate simple moving average for time to render screen. 0.1 factor used as smoothing
        // value.
        this.deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - this.deltaTime) * 0.1f;
    }

    // Returns an ad request with custom ad targeting.
    private AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
            .AddKeyword("game")
            .SetGender(Gender.Male)
            .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
            .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
            .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
            .Build();
    }

    private void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-7624023175090985/4535603801";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest(), adUnitId);
    }

    private void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("Interstitial is not ready yet");
        }
    }

    private void ShowRewardBasedVideo()
    {
        if (this.rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("Reward based video ad is not ready yet");
        }
    }

    #region RewardBasedVideo callback handlers

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        UIText.text = "Watch a short video\nfor an extra life ?";
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        UIText.text = "Watch a short video\nfor an extra life ?";
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        musicPlayer.Pause();
        player.disableMovment = true;
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        musicPlayer.Pause();
        player.disableMovment = true;
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        UIText.text = "Watch a short video\nfor an extra life ?";
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        player.rewardAdUI.SetActive(false);
        UIText.text = "Watch a short video\nfor an extra life ?";
        player.disableMovment = false;

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("music") == 1)
        {
            musicPlayer.Play();
        }

        Lives.addLives(1);
        player.RespawnPlayer();
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        UIText.text = "Watch a short video\nfor an extra life ?";
    }

    public void secondChance()
    {
        UIText.text = "Loading video...\nplease wait.";
        this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        player.disableMovment = false;

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("music") == 1)
        {
            musicPlayer.Play();
        }

        player.gameOver();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So the 2nd to last function called secondChance() is what runs to play the ad. On my android device, this plays the test rewarded video.

After the ad plays, the HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded function should be called but it doesnt. Any help at all is appriciated

Comment: You say, that the ad plays, but the callback isn't called? I'm asking because in your script secondChance() only calls RequestRewardBasedVideo() and ShowRewardBasedVideo() is never called in your code.

Comment: Yes thats right, ShowRewardBasedVideo is called in theHandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded call back. This shows the video after it has loads. So it seems at least 1 callback is firing

Comment: May I suggest removing your appId from your code?  Not sure about Google's AdMob, but most Ad Systems strongly advise against sharing your ID.

Comment: @Eddge hi, this is just the test id they provide

Comment: Good to know, I just wanted to make sure you weren't posting something that could affect your app.

Comment: Well you do exactly the same things I did, execpt for a few differences. The only differences are, that I create a new AdRequest without setting all the parameter, "AdRequest.Builder().Build()". The second difference is, that I set the callback after I loaded the ad. But I would be surprised, if these two things really make a difference. Other than that the only difference might be the version. I assume the ad plays until the end, and is not previously stopped by itself or you.

Comment: I haven't done alot with AdMobs, so their API may already protect against this but are you sure that `MobileAds.SetiOSAppPauseOnBackground(true);` isn't causing an issue on your android device since it isnt in the #If for iPhone?

Comment: @SebastianKilb this is strange, what unity package version do you have? i downloaded the newest one. I have been stuck on this for like 2 days.

Comment: @Eddge im testing it on an android device so im not sure that would make a difference in this case even if it did for ios

Comment: @RachelDockter thats why I am asking your testing on Android and that reads like a function for iPhone.

Comment: @Eddge oh i see what you mean, ill take it out and see if that makes a difference, update: its just used to pause the app while the video plays which i do manually in my code anyway

Comment: Looking at the source it looks like it does nothing on android https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/blob/master/source/plugin/Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Platforms/Android/MobileAdsClient.cs

Comment: @Eddge thats fine, i manually disable the player and music while the ad is playing and i dont think this should effect the callback being called

Comment: @RachelDockter I use version 3.7.1

Comment: @SebastianKilb thanks i will try with that version instead

Answer (score 7):

I found a Silent Error after debugging in Android Studio, its due to threading issues in Unity.

Solution : Call your handling event in main thread (in Update Method)

```
bool isAdClosed = false;
bool isRewarded = false;
void Update()
{
    if (isAdClosed)
    {
        if (isRewarded)
        {
            // do all the actions
            // reward the player
            isRewarded = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Ad closed but user skipped ads, so no reward 
           // Ad your action here 
        }
        isAdClosed = false;  // to make sure this action will happen only once.
    }
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    print("HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed event received");

    RequestRewardBasedVideo(); // to load Next Videoad
    isAdClosed = true;

}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
    string type = args.Type;
    double amount = args.Amount;
    print("HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded event received for " + amount.ToString() + " " +
            type);
        isRewarded = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Vivek's solution worked for me on Unity v20212.1.15f1, although I had to put the code in my GameManager Update function as the AdManager Update function wasn't running when the RewardedAd was shown.