# Can't trigger events in unity 2018

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, game-development

Hi i am trying to implement admob rewarded video for my game. I have imported admob sdk and implemented all required methods. The ad is loading and showing correctly but the problem is that i have added events in my code to detect when the ad is finished. Unfortunately my events are not called.[registered event listeners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INDw6.png) [this is where i request and show rewarded video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5oo.png)

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857817/reward-ad-callback-is-not-firing

Comment: see that post for the answer by Vivek

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i cant figure out that what i have to write in update, my event or something else...?

Comment: Did you check his answer ? Just set some bools in the event handlers and check if the bools are true in the update.  if its true then call the function that you need like test.SetActive(true)  etc

Comment: Also why are you calling RequestRewarded() if the ad is loaded ?

Comment: ad is not loaded it only gets loaded when i request it, and i have already checked added some bools and also tried that method which is described in the post u showed me

Comment: that solution works for me well. maybe you are missing something